# CSS3 Input styling

Tags: css

I'm trying to create some OS X like text inputs for my website. They've been coming out very nice in CSS3 browsers. The problem is, there is no border and the background is white. So if a browser does not support `box-shadow` or `-moz-box-shadow` or `-webkit-box-shadow`, You wouldn't be able to tell that it's a text input, you wouldn't be able to see it. I need a border for non CSS3 browsers only...
To get a better idea here is the CSS I wrote: http://jsfiddle.net/wUMDG/
Is that possible?

I forgot to mention, adding a border makes it ugly... so I don't want to show the border if it's CSS3.

Comment: Adding a 1px border doesn't affect the look at all. Make it 1px and almost a very light gray.

Comment: The term CSS3 is being used very loosely here. The prefixed properties, for one, aren't even part of the spec. And what defines a CSS3 browser?

Comment: @BoltClock One that supports CSS3

Comment: @BoltClock that would be webkit based, like Chrome 4+ and Safari, Opera 10+, partial in Firefox 3.6+ and IE8+

Comment: @MichaelRader Tried it with `#BCBCBC` didn't like it. It looks different...

Comment: @fskreuz You mean Firefox 3.5+ and IE9+

Comment: Even IE9 doesn't support transitions... IE10+

Comment: @user1090389 my bad, i got it confused. IE8 supports additional selectors and not CSS3. updated my answer with a fiddle.

Comment: IE7 and IE8 support advanced attribute selectors and the general sibling combinator, which, @fskreuz, *are* level 3 selectors. IE5+ supports `overflow-x/y` and `word-wrap`. These must be CSS3 browsers too, right? The point I'm making here is to be careful not to use the term too loosely or naïvely. Most browsers support some CSS level 3 modules here and there, so you can't simply say this browser supports CSS3 and that doesn't. It's just way too fragmented.

Comment: @BoltClock yes but I'm obviously discussing box shadows and border radii - mainly box shadows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest placing a border for older browsers. only browsers with CSS3 support will read the CSS3 properties. older browsers will ignore the CSS3.

also, with the `radius` property, you can curve the borders. you need not use shadows for curved areas. that way, if the browser does not support CSS3, it will use square borders instead.

for more info, check the CSS2 and CSS3 sections:

http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html

**UPDATE:**

check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wUMDG/2/

and it will fail as square borders if no CSS3 support. but the blue and grey border will stay

Comment: You don't get it, I want OS X like so I want the shadows. But I need a fallback for IE6, IE7 & IE8. 

Under breath "Internet Explorer" (rolls eyes)...

Comment: well, that's your only fallback using plain CSS. older browsers like IE6, 7 and 8 do not understand CSS3 and thus not render your shadow. otherwise, you have to use image backgrounds.

Comment: here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UuvNc/) similar concept though left in the shadow on focus

Comment: @TomIngram the shadows and focus have a fallback but the curved border won't

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at CSS3 Pie:

http://css3pie.com/

It should help you out in most cases.

Comment: Maybe... I was against it originally because I was going for light weight, and a bunch of htc files wouldn't be part of the principle, but I just remembered other browsers do not support the `behavior` attribute and wouldn't download the file... so maybe...

Comment: Unfortunately, box-shadows do not work on inputs on the iPhone, iPad and possibly other mobiles. So I ended up using both borders and PIE. However, I feel compelled to accept a border answer...